# Tsql: what is the best way to retrieve some records with  a specific criteria?

Tags: performance, t-sql, execution-time

I have a table (Cars) which saves some characteristics car like EngineNo, LastProductionStepId, NodyNo, ...

Besides, I have another table (CarSteps) which saves all steps that a specific car should pass during its manufacturing proccess like Engine Assigning(Id = 2), Engraving(3), PrePaint(4), Paint(5), AfterPaint(6), Confirmation(7), Delivery(8)

I would like to get all cars that are between PrePaint and Confirmation **at the moment**:

```
select    cr.Id, cr.BodyNo, cr.LastStepId 
from      Cars cr WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join CarSteps steps WITH (NOLOCK) on cr.Id = trace.CarId and    cr.LastStepId=trace.StepId 
where       
     cr.LastStepId >= 4
    AND cr.[Status] = 1
    AND steps.[Status] = 1
    AND not exists (    select  * 
            from    CarSteps steps1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
            where   steps1.CarId = cr.Id 
                AND steps1.StepId >= 7                                  AND steps1.Status = 1
             )
```

Because CarSteps has many records (44 million) the query is slow .
what is your opinion? is there any better way to get those cars?

Comment: You test for the "done" steps with an inner join, but then for the "future steps" with a sub-query. Have you tried doing both tests as a sub-query (which should be able to use the CarSteps tables indices for faster searching)? Additionally, I would recommend using the query profiler in SQL Server Management Studio to identify which part of the query takes the most work.

Comment: Can't you use `cr.LastStepId between 4 and 7`? No need to look in `CarSteps` if you have the current `StepId` in `LastStepId`.

Comment: Need to see the PK on Cars.  My gut feel is that you are not in 3rd normal form and that is causing problems.  It appears you are trying to to use the cars table track history and current status in the same table and that is not good.  History is multi-value and current status is single-value.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query I see a join from Cars to CarSteps, I see you joining to trace.CarId and trace.StepId is.  trace is not defined in your query.

```
from      
 Cars cr WITH (NOLOCK) inner join 
 CarSteps steps WITH (NOLOCK) on 
  cr.Id = trace.CarId and    
  cr.LastStepId=trace.StepId
```

I may be able to help if i have better understand the fully query.
What does the execution plan reveal?